# Dart how to add complex parameter

Tags: http, dart, request, query-string

I need to get url with query parameters, but I dont know how.
I need this -> "entityTypeId=172&filter[id]=1&filter[id]=3&filter[id]=5".

In JS i can do like that

```
var httpBuildQuery = require('http-build-query');
var params = {
entityTypeId: 172,
filter: {
    id: [1, 3, 5]
}};
const url = url + "?" + httpBuildQuery(params);

console.log(httpBuildQuery(params));
```

In PHP

```
$params = array(
'filter' => array ('ID' => array('1', '3', '5'),),
'entityTypeId' => 172,
);
http_build_query($params);
```

In dart I tried this

```
var uri = Uri(
  scheme: 'http',
  host: 'b24-ybr1v4.bitrix24.ru',
  path: '/rest/1/token/crm.item.list.json',
  queryParameters: {
    'entityTypeId': '172',
    'filter': [
      {'id': '1'}
    ],
  },
);
```

But in this case I get error:

```
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown while handling a gesture:
Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'IdentityMap<String, String>'
```

How to get parameter like "filter[id]"?

Answer (score 0):

You could try moving the `[id]` part into the query parameter key.

```dart
var uri = Uri(
  scheme: 'http',
  host: 'b24-ybr1v4.bitrix24.ru',
  path: '/rest/1/token/crm.item.list.json',
  queryParameters: {
    'entityTypeId': '172',
    'filter[id]': ['1', '3', '5'],
  },
);
```